# Surjectivity of a surjective restricted ring homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Let $f : R_1 \rightarrow R_2$ a unitary ring homomorphism.
Define $f^* : R_{1}^* \rightarrow R_2^* : x \mapsto f(x)$.
Is $f^*$ surjective when $f$ is surjective?

---

One can show that $f^*$ is well defined, because units are mapped to units. If $f$ is injective, then $f^*$ is injective. Moreover $f$ is a group homomorfism, so
$$|f(R^*_1)|\  \text{divides} \ |R^*_2|$$
Still I fail to prove surjectivity. I also fail to give a counterexample. Can you help me?

Comment: $R_1 = \mathbb{Z},\; R_2 = \mathbb{Z}/(17)$.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induced homomorphism between the unit groups cannot be surjective if the ring $R_2$ contains more units that $R_1$. A ring with very few units is $\mathbb{Z}$, and most of its quotients have more than two units. If the kernel of the homomorphism is a prime ideal, every nonzero element of the quotient is a unit, so for any prime $p > 3$ (and most composites), the canonical homomorphism

$$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(p)$$

induces a non-surjective homomorphism of the unit groups.

Of course, if a ring homomorphism is surjective and injective, the induced homomorphism of the unit groups is also an isomorphism.